# How to transfer the extracted value of One Request to CSV and again Reuse the CSV data in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I sent a JDBC Request 2 times in same thread and used while controller after those two JDBC request containing verification HTTP Request. How can i transfer the value that is obtained from JDBC request and use it HTTP request(which is under while loop)  . Is there any way so that i can extract the value from JDBC request ,store it in CSV and and again use the same value as testcase in another http request in same thread ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to pass a value that you have captured from JDBC Request response, you need to declare variables in "Variable names" and use them in your http request.

[JDBC Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mjPF.png)

If your query return n rows the values are captured as id_1,id_2,......id_n

So you can use which value based on your requirement as ${id_1} in http request sampler